# Ionic and InAppBrowser does not work toghether

Tags: android, url, ionic-framework

I need to wrap a URL inside the ionic application. I test with windows 8, inside chrome broswer.

- On Windows Chrome: redirect to the page inside browser
- On Android Phone: close the application without any warning or something else in console.

Please give me a solution to what I need without using iframes.

I followed all the info that each docs gave me and this is how I implement it:

`app.js` file:

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }

      if (window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })

  .controller('CheckController', function($scope, $cordovaInAppBrowser) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
      onDeviceReady();
    }



    function onDeviceReady() {


      window.open = $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_self', {
          location: 'no',
          hidden: 'yes'
        }).then(function(event) {
          alert('success');
        })
        .catch(function(event) {
          console.log(event);
        });
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>

  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter">

  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Lunch External App Demo</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content ng-controller="CheckController">
      <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>

    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working on Android:

```js
 ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
            // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
            onDeviceReady3();
        });

function onDeviceReady3(){
            var options = {
                location: 'no',
                clearcache: 'no',
                toolbar: 'yes', //only for IOS
                hidden:'yes'
            };
               
                $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://google.com', '_self', options)
                    .then(function(event) {
                        // success
                        alert("success");
                    })
                    .catch(function(event) {
                        // error
                        alert("error");
                    });
                $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
        }
```